# How to send and receive data simultaneously via TCP/IP C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, network-programming

Trying to build an application that will act as client connecting to a remote server on a predefined IP and Port. The server will periodically send messages and also forward messages from other clients. I want to be able to receive all oncoming messages without interrupting the connection or state to send data to the server.
My current implementation uses sockets on which I switch between receiving and sending messages every 30 seconds.
This can mean I might miss messages during the time I am sending.

Comment: Use async sockets, no need to switch anything. And you won’t miss anything with TCP, they may be delayed though.

Comment: If you're not bound to any (custom) protocol, I recommend using WebSockets. The advances is that the protocol is a standard and it's easy to use them in several other languages. So your focus gets back to the functionality/application you were working on. You can find some in nuget.

Comment: Currently using Async Client Socket with the help of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example

Seems to be working fine for now and hope to observe this more. Will keep watching this thread for more feedback.